# In CSS: What does this mean :

Tags: css

**In  CSS**: What does this mean:

```
   padding: 12px 0;

   transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

Comment: MDN is the reference you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

padding : 12px 0;

It's mean in css, padding : top&bottom, left&right;

transition: all 0.3s ease;

"all" transition effect apply on property you set on css.
"0.3s" time when apply transition
"ease"  specifies a transition effect with a slow start, then fast, then end slowly

Answer (score 1):

Padding top and bottom 12px 
Padding left and right 0px

All the transitions like hover,active should take 0.3 seconds and the timing function used is "ease"

Answer (score 0):

The first Line creates a padding of 12px for top and bottom and a padding of 0px for left and right.

The second line creates a transition effect for all properties (like hover or active) with a transition duration of 0.3s and a transition timing function of "ease". transition is a shorthand for various transition properties in css.
Please refer to the following link for further information.
[css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)